# BluetoothLEClient UWP Sample crashing

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, visual-studio-2017

I need to develop an application for Windows 10 that can interface with a BLE device I have with custom GATT services. I understand the the correct way to do this is using the BLE support within UWP. So I am attempting to start by getting the BluetoothLEClient sample running from the following repository:
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

I have opened the BluetoothLEClient sample in Visual Studio 2017. My initial attempt to build this for x64 to run on my local machine had deployment errors, stating that the version of Windows Universal Runtime on the target was not correct.

I then changed the Target Version and Min Version to match the version that I have installed, which is:
Widows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0 Build 14393).

After this the applications builds and starts to run, but then crashes with an unhandled exception, and states that the attached debugger is not setup for unhandled exceptions. I then changed the settings of the debugger to 'Mixed (Managed and Native)' and re ran the application.

At this point, it crashed on the line InitializeComponent(); in Scenario1_DiscoverServer().

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF86D1ED489 (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in BluetoothLEClient.exe: 0xC000027B: An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters: 0x0000019CB327BFD0, 0x0000000000000001). occurred

Please can you explain the cause of this issue, and how to overcome it?

Or alternatively if there is a better route towards developing a Windows program to interface to custom GATT services on a BLE device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out, the project seems to be dependant on having the Windows 10 Creators Update installed.

Once I installed this reopened the Visual Studio project, it runs without any problems.